# android ListView requestFocusFromTouch setSelection smoothScrollToPosition seems to be ignored

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have at first look very simple problem with ListView.

I use it in a very classical way:

```
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myid);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(result);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When using this for the first time, listView is at the top which is not suprising. However when I clear adapter and puts new data

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(result);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it keeps the previously selected position. But I would like to scroll the list to the top again.

I tried:

```
listView.setSelection(0);

listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
listView.setSelection(0);

listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

All seems to be ignored. :( How to force listView to return to the first element.

Comment: What I can add, I use ViewPager (v4). Perhaps it has some influence on that?

Answer (score 0):

when you call for setSelection(0), you setting the item in the 0 position to be the selected one and the scrolling to position 0, so in fact you scrolling from position 0 to position 0